# Trouble displaying a clickable image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Stackoverflow and new to Rails and I'm trying to display a clickable image in Rails. What I want to do is display the image, make it clickable and when you click on the image you can use the image viewer to zoom in. This works:

```
<%= link_to "Show Images", "image_path" %>
```

where image_path is a direct URL. When you click on the "Show Images" link, you're able to zoom in on the image. Instead of showing the text "Show Images" I want to show the image. I've tried this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag "image_path", "image_path" %>
```

But its giving me errors. I even tried putting parenthesies around the fields but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks,

-LRC-

Answer (score 6):

The following should work.

```
<%= link_to image_path do %>
    <%= image_tag image_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks everett1992, only problem with that solution is I'm seeing the text and not the images on the page. I am able to click it and it brings me to the image, just not showing the image on the page.

Comment: Sorry, I see that you updated it and it works! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you put the parentheses like this, it should work:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image_path"), "image_path" %>
```